# How to tell if content has been migrated

Tags: 7, migrations

I am using drupal2drupal migration. How can I indicate that some content has been migrated as opposed to being manually added.

Comment: Perhaps by the creation date you might be able to tell.

Answer (score 2):

You could alter the incoming data and attach a taxonomy tag, like 'migrated', to indicate this.

You could also add (migrated) in the title, but you would have to ensure this does not affect users, terms, URL aliases, etc. Hence why I suggest a taxonomy term. I am not that familiar with D2D API but I know this is very easy to do with Migrate Framework.

Comment: what about adding a new boolean field (migrated) ?

Comment: Whatever works best for you.

Answer (score 0):

It has been a while since I have done a proper D2D migration (I do more imports from non-Drupal sources using custom scripts), but you should be able to examine the migration map table(s) for nodes.  If the destination node ID exists, then you know that the node in question was migrated.

However, when I have used D2D I would prefer to add `field_old_nid` to each node and add a mapping from `nid => field_old_nid` for that.  Then just hide that field from public view.

I have found that having the old nid as a field can come in handy down the road.  For example, when you have your old and new sites up, you can easily add an link from the old site to the new site for debug/QA purposes, using the http://example.com/node/nid URL for the old site.  I also seem to recall using some filter shenanigans to fixup LinkIt style links in body content.

Answer (score 0):

New tables are created for each migration type, the old and new Entity IDs are stored in that table. The name is different for each table, so I can't specifically tell you the table name, but if you look in the database you can see the tables that start with migrate_. A query on that table can tell you if the content has been migrated.